# Pixel Based Responsive Web Design

Tags: css, responsive-design

Most responsive designs use fluid layouts, however:

1. Is it possible to use pixel/fixed based layout for a responsive design (obviously the breakpoints will be far more noticeable)
2. Are there any examples of pixel based responsive designs out there?

Comment: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: http://vote.nsw.gov.au/ this looks like it's what you're talking about.

I'm sure you have a good reason for this... but surely it can't be that good. Go responsive, go all the way.

Answer (score 2):

You could have different stylesheets for differently sized browser windows, by using `CSS Media Queries`.

Source: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Demo: http://css-tricks.com/examples/MediaQueriesSidebar/

Resize your browser and see how the page adapts to different window sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll be very difficult and there'll be a lot of code to write using px's depending on the different viewport sizes. I think it's achievable if you don't have many viewports to support, e.g. only the mobile size and the 1024px desktop size to support.

However if your design layouts can be done via "grid", you can use [Heroku Fluid Layouts](http://grids.heroku.com/)

Use the normal px one for the desktop view and then use media queries to override with the fluid in % grid.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much to add as the other answers cover your question, but, if you chose to use pixels for your media queries the breakpoints will be noticeable but you could always animate them for a nice effect on resize e.g.

```
.container {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .container {width:320px; background:red;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .container {width:480px; background:green;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the typical take is that responsive design without fluid grids is actually adaptive design, as adaptive design is a super set of responsive design. Can you have responsive design without fluid grids? Strictly speaking, probably not. [More explanation](http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/adaptive-vs-responsive-whats-the-difference.php).

But if you want your website to look good on multiple screen sizes using pixel values, you certainly can use adaptive design. It isn't as robust and won't work on as many devices, but depending on the project that isn't always necessary. If you are looking for a framework to get you started, you might want to check out [Skeleton.js](http://www.getskeleton.com/). I've used it before at work when we want to get something quick and simple up like this [iOS app promo page](http://www.npr.org/services/mobile/pm/index.html).

Hope that helps.